# Observable Lists in flutter with mobx

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I am trying to make an observable list (i.e. when an element of the list is changed, removed, or added, I would like the UI to updated). I know that mobx has something called an "observableList", and so this seems like it should be possible. However, I am having issues implementing it. I currently have the following code in my mobx store file:

```
var metrics = Observable([.5,.5,.5]);
```

Then later, I try to change one of the elements like so:

```
metrics[index] = data;
```

I get the error:

**The method '[]=' isn't defined for the class 'Observable>'.**

Is there a way to create an observable list (or better yet, an observable dictionary) in flutter, or is that not implemented yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With MobX you need to create methods annotated with `@action` to be notified about changes over an `Observable`.

## In your Store you must have something like

```
@observable
var metrics = ObservableList<int>([.5,.5,.5]);

// This is action method. You need to use this method to react
// your UI properly when something changes in your observable list.
@action
void addItem(float data) => metrics.add(data);

// the same for this method but with a different operation.
@action
void removeItem(float data) => metrics.remove(data);
```

#In your UI layer

```
Observer(
 builder: (context) =>
   ListView.builder(
     itemCount: yourStore.metrics.length,
     builder: (_, index) => Text('${yourStore.metrics[index]}'),
  ),
);
```

In this case after some change in `yourStore.metrics` observable list the `Observer` builder callback will be fired and the list view will be updated.

Comment: Is this true? In the docs, they demonstrate Observables triggering Reactions without having to wrap them in Actions. I thought Actions are just for making multiple changes atomic, ie, trigger a single Reaction...? https://pub.dev/packages/mobx

Comment: @HariHonor You are correct. Additionally, you do not need to wrap an ObservableList with `@observable`, and you do not need to wrap list-modifying actions with `@action`

https://pub.dev/documentation/mobx/latest/mobx/ObservableList-class.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use my code. You need to add ".of" to initialize the list

```
ObservableList<int> values = ObservableList<int>.of([1,2,3]);
```

Later you can use it like this.

```
values[index] = data;
```